# HTML5: how do I disable all links after any one of them are clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is what my current link looks like:

`<a href="/board/take_turn?id=313&x=1&y=2" data-remote="true" class="square">
              <span class="ttt_square"> 
                &nbsp;
              </span>
</a>`

I know it's not ajax because the jQuery ajax:success type events are never invoked.

This is teh site that I'm working on: http://ttt-ai.heroku.com/

Comment: "all links" = all links in the page?

Comment: all links after yes is clicked on the page. each of the square links, a.square

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('a').click(function() {
           $(this).attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');
        });
    });
</script>
```

And if you will add a class to your link for being more specific; let's say

```
<a class="disableAfterClick" href="/board/take_turn?id=313&x=1&y=2" data-remote="true"> <span class="ttt_square"> &nbsp; </span> </a>
```

than

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('a.disableAfterClick').click(function() {
           $(this).attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to disable all links on a page you can use this:

```
$("a").live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    return false;
});
```

Or you can target specific links like this:

```
$("a.disabledLink").live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    return false;
});

<a href="/board/take_turn?id=313&x=1&y=2" data-remote="true" class="disabledLink">
    <span class="ttt_square">&nbsp;</span>
</a>
```

Comment: No need to `preventDefault()` and `return false`. That's just redundant and redundant

Answer (score 1):

```
var $a = $("a");

$a.click(function() {
     $a.click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
     }
});
```

no need to traverse twice, or if you do

```
$("a").live("click", function() {
     $("a").click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
     }
});
```

Comment: Unless you have dynamically changing links?

Comment: none of the links are available at page load. which might be why none of the answers work.

Comment: then use live function to bind to dynamic elements

Comment: added live; @DerNalia you know it would be much easier to help if you include all the details necessary, it is hard to guess

Answer (score 1):

You can use e.preventDefault() .