# How to disable submit button on submit for many forms - generic function to any form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit

I'm not an expert in jQuery - and I know this is easy - but I cannot find the solution for this.

I have a page with 10 alerts (cancel, confirm, resend..) - with 10 forms and 10 submit buttons.

How I can disable the submit button on submit form with a generic function ?

I know how I can disable 1 form.

```
$('form#id').submit(function(){
  $(this).find(':input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

but with this I need to write 10x - a function for each form...

```
$('.form').submit(function(){
  $(this).find(':input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

I try this but, didn't work..

I need a function to works for any form..

All forms are like this:

```
            <form id="cancelform" action="cancel.asp">
            <input type="hidden" name="codec" id="codec" value="121">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger bk-rd-off" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> NO</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success bg-success-800 bk-rd-off"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> YES</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: use a function and send the if of the as parameter to the function and work out everything else from there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable submit functionality for all forms on a HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283755/disable-submit-functionality-for-all-forms-on-a-html-page)

Comment: Hi @MikeMcCaughan tks! I read the solution, but my question is about to disable the submit button ON SUBMIT with 1 function only - and works for any form in the page.  (because if I have 10 forms I need 10 functions)

Comment: The accepted answer on that question is a single line of code that will disable submission of all forms on the page wherever you put it...

Comment: Yes @MikeMcCaughan, but my question is about how to disable the submit button ON SUBMIT and with ONLY 1 Function for any form. That question don't solve the problem. As I said in my question - how to disable the button I know. how to disable ON SUBMIT - I know. I don't know how to disable on submit and with only 1 generic function - to works to all forms that I have in the html. Without this I need to write 1 function to disable for each form - because the method that I know needs the form id. here I got 2 complete solutions - with vanilla JS and with JQuery.

Answer (score 6):

You don't even need jQuery for this, feel free to use vanilla JS:

```
document.querySelectorAll('form input[type="submit"]')
  .forEach(input => input.disabled = true);
```

Or if you want to disable form *submission* and not just the buttons, you can do something similar to `preventDefault` on every `submit` event:

```
document.querySelectorAll('form').forEach((form) => {
  form.addEventListener('submit', e => e.preventDefault());
});
```

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance tks for your precious time and Help! I'm not an expert in JS - but I test the function (copy-paste only) - and didn't works. I have alert messages in the page - like "do you want to cancel this? - YES/NO" or "Do you want to send the email?" - and the submit button is not disable the user send 100 emails clicking.. I know how to disable the button on submit for 1 form (with the form ID) - but I want a solution to disable for all forms - then I dont need to write 10x the same funcition.. tks!!

Comment: `didn't works` is not very informative, please elaborate? If those alert messages are relevant to the problem, please post the relevant code in your question. I can only see the code you've posted so far.

Comment: I edit the question with the form code. All forms are the same - change only the ID and the ASP page. tks a lot @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 3):

Select all the forms, then onSubmit, use the `event.target` to get a reference to just that single form that is being submitted, find it's submit button, and disable it. Should work for 1 form, or 100 forms....

[Example JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oxyc1br7/1/)

```
$('form').submit(function(event){
  // disable future submits
    $(event.target).find('[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true); 
});
```

Depending on your needs, you might also include an `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: hi @TJBlackman, tks for your precious time to help me! Works fine, but I need a solution to disable the button ON SUBMIT. to avoid user to click many times. I know how I can do this for each form (using #ID) - but I don't know how I do to any form (and avoid to write 1 function for each form) - do you understand? sorry for my english. TKS!

Answer (score 2):

You're scoping adding the disabled prop to the $(this) selector which is the current form being submitted. If you want to disable all submit buttons you can use a global query selector on your submit callback:

```
$('.form').submit(function() {
  $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled',true);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you're trying to use `find` when you can just do this:

```js
$('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit"/>
<input type="submit"/>
<input type="submit"/>
```

Comment: Hi @jdgregson. Tks for your precious time and help! I have many alert messages in the page - like "do you want to cancel this? - YES/NO" or "Do you want to send the email?" - and if the submit button is not disable the user send 100 emails clicking.. I know how to disable the button on submit for 1 form (with the form ID) - but I want a solution to disable for all forms - then I dont need to write 10x the same funcition.. tks!!